# python 列と行のデータを照らし合わせて集計したい

Tags: python, pandas

データ前処理でどうしても解決できない部分があり質問させていただきます。

2つのテーブルで1つはユーザーIDに基づいたテレビ番組の視聴データ（0：見てない　1：見た）、
2つ目は上記テレビ番組のIDに基づいたCMの出稿データとなっており、製品名、会社名はダミーにしております。

今回やろうとしていることは製品ごとに出稿されたCMをユーザーがいくつ見たのかを集計したく
Aという製品は〇回、Bという製品は〇回といったアウトプットのイメージなのですがどうしても
調べてもやり方が分からず、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

テレビ番組視聴データサンプル
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ySTpfMASAqerC-vWrMX5oAmdT3DxBHno/view?usp=sharing
テレビCM出稿データサンプル
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qxGqaUQrtrMpTkMptb6slyq22fNyfvRO/view?usp=sharing

現在実行中のコード

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tv = pd.read_csv('sample_tv.csv')
tv

tvcm = pd.read_csv('sample_tvcm.csv',encoding='cp932')
tvcm
```

ご回答いただいた実行結果

ありがとうございます。いただいたコードで実行したところ

```
  df = (tvcm.groupby('item_name')
              .agg({
                'title_code_variable': lambda x: tv[x].sum()
              })
              .applymap(lambda x: x.sum())
              .reset_index()
              .rename(columns={
                'item_name': '製品名',
                'title_code_variable': '視聴回数'
          }))
```

の実行後に

```
ValueError: Must produce aggregated value
```

となってしまったのですが何かこちら側での問題が考えられますでしょうか？

Comment: 1つのテレビ番組に複数社のCMが入ることが良くあると思うのですが、それはどのように表現されていて、どのように考慮すべきものでしょうか？ それとも今は考えなくて良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 今回に関しては1つの番組に対して1つの製品CMとして表現されておりますので一旦考慮しない形で問題ありません！情報不足ですみません。

Answer (score 1):

製品名でグループ化して sum を取ります。

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tv = pd.read_csv('sample_tv.csv')
tvcm = pd.read_csv('sample_tvcm.csv', encoding='cp932')

df = (tvcm.groupby('item_name')
          .agg({
            'title_code_variable': lambda x: tv[x].sum()
          })
          .applymap(lambda x: x.sum())
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={
            'item_name': '製品名',
            'title_code_variable': '視聴回数'
          }))
```

`print(df.to_markdown(index=False))`

| 製品名 | 視聴回数 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 1 |

Comment: @metropolis様　ありがとうございます。頂いた内容で実行したところエラーが出てしまい投稿欄に詳細を記載させていただきました。

Comment: こちらの実行環境は `Python 3.9/Pandas 1.3.4` になります。また、データは質問欄にある URL からダウンロードしました。

Comment: 承知いたしました。ありがとうございます。バージョンをアップデートし再度実行してみます。